# Review-banned users might be having issues with viewing suggested edits from a question page

Tags: support, bug, suggested-edits, review-suspension

I'm currently review banned <sup><sub>(this is not by any means a complaint about my ban, it's necessary background info)</sub></sup>, and I've noticed a while ago that when I try to view pending suggested edits from a `/question/<question-id>` page (not from the review queue), I now get "*An error occurred when loading the review item. Please try again.*" instead of being able to view the pending suggested edit (whereas I used to be able to see the pending suggested edit- even while review banned). Trying again as the error toast suggests results in the same error. Is this intended behaviour? Or is it a bug?

Here's some more info: Three requests are made (real example):

- `/review/suggested-edit-popup/76384273?_=1685679030700` status 200
- `/Content/Img/progress-dots.gif` status 200
- `/review/next-task/34485035?isInPopup=true` status 500